# How to read a specific part of a line in a text document in VB 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to read a specific part of a text document which will allow me to allow the user into the program.

The problem i'm having with the code is that it is able to complete the first if statement but no the second - it reads the username but not the password.

```
Dim usernames() As String = File.ReadAllLines(Dir$("Usernames.txt"))
For RecordNumber = 0 To UBound(usernames)
    If Trim(Mid(usernames(RecordNumber), 1, 15)) = TextBox1.Text Then
        If Trim(Mid(usernames(RecordNumber), 15, 30)) = TextBox2.Text Then 
            MsgBox("Password is correct")
        End If
    End If
Next RecordNumber
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks